# Django translations with language code precedence / fallback

Tags: python, django, django-multilingual

I'm looking for advice on how best to enhance Django's translation framework.

The aim is to modify the translation system so that instead of immediately falling back to the **`msgid`** when a mapping cannot be found, the system first attempts to obtain a translation from another (predefined) language code.

*Background:*

The desire to first attempt to fallback to another language, rather than **`msgids`** is because the current set of 'msgids' are not human readable. The project uses tokens/identifiers. The human readable english is in it's own translation PO file alongside all the other languages. This is advantageous when it comes to tweaking the english copy... there's no need to touch the other language files.

*The attempt:*

```
def ugettext_fb(message):
    trans_output = translation.ugettext(message)

    if trans_output == message:
        preset_language = translation.get_language()
        logger.warn('Missing \'%s\' translation for %s' % (preset_language, message))

        translation.activate(settings.LANGUAGE_FALLBACK)
        trans_output = translation.ugettext(message)
        translation.activate(preset_language)

    return trans_output
```

This wrapper seems to work although I'm interested if SO folks know of a better way?

Also, looking at the [Django source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/translation/__init__.py), it looks like I'll need to wrap each of the `gettext(_lazy)` functions individually. Is there a smarter way to do that?

Comment: The only way AFAIK, is to remove empty translations (before compilation, ie: with https://pypi.python.org/pypi/polib), then it will fallback to the base language when the msgid is not found.

Comment: That's an interesting approach... I'll look into it.

Comment: Did you find a better way?

Comment: I was pulled to a different project and didn't take it further.